# Updating gridview row NOT finding data is gridview row

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I have looked for a couple of days now and for some reason I am unable to solve my issue.  I have a gridview control and wanting to update the row that is selected.  I am trying to populate vidInformaiton class, passes to my stored procedure.

```
                  <asp:GridView ID="gvVideos" CssClass="gvVideosClass" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerId"
            OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" EmptyDataText="No records has been added.">
            <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="customerId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("customerId")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblcustomerID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("customerId")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fid" ItemStyle-Width="50">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        <input type="hidden" name="vidId" value='<%# Eval("fId")%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>

        <ItemStyle Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("typeContent")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("typeContent")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Youtube ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ytid") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ytid") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("descvid") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("descvid") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("thumbnail") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("thumbnail") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SubmitDate">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("submitdate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("submitdate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("active")%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Categories">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("categories") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("categories") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sort order">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sortord") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sortord") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="150"/>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />


    </div>
```

My code behind look like this.  not sure what I am missing. I can't seem to get the values from the row.  I have tried everything, DirectCast, FindControl.

```
Protected Sub OnRowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim updVid As New VidInformation
    Dim updVidRecord As New vidController


    Dim row = gvVideos.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    updVid.customerId = row.Cells(1).Text.ToString

    gvVideos.EditIndex = -1
    gvVideos.DataSource = updVidRecord.UpdateVidRecord(updVid)
    bindGridview()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to get new values after Save button is pressed? Then just use `e.NewValues["title"]`

Comment: Yes so when the user updates the info and hits "update".  How does it know which row it's updating?

Comment: That's confusing. If user hits "Update" inside the row, then it is obvious for ASP.NET which row was updated. If they click this button `Update Sort Order` I very much doubt there will be any row update at all. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: sorry, it's not the sort order that I am concerned about it's simply updating the current row information, I am NOT able to get the value from the cell from the current row.  I use the class VidInformation to pass my values to a stored procedure.

Comment: i would assume that it would use EditTemplate, which I should be able to use customerId.text???

Comment: Well, then I repeat my suggestion - did you try `e.NewValues`? This is exactly the way to get new values, since by the time post back from update is handled on server grid view row is no longer in Edit mode, and thus the controls you are looking for do not exist on the page.

Comment: Andrei, yes this did work I was trying to use customerId.text however updVid.customerId = e.NewValues("customerId") was the correct syntax.  HUGE Thank you....

Comment: how do I mark this answered???

Comment: I have converted this comment thread into a proper answer. Feel free to mark this as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Converting series of helpful comments to an answer*

The correct way to get new values posted to edited GridView row is to use `NewValues` property of the even args object:

```
Protected Sub OnRowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    ...
    Dim updVid As New VidInformation
    updVid.customerId = e.NewValues("customerId")
    ...
End Sub
```

As to why initial approach did not work. Important thing to realize is that GridView row in question was in edit mode during the previous load of the page. During the post back which edit button triggered new values are posted to the server, but the row is no longer in edit mode, so there are no more edit controls to be found in this row. Thus the method described above is the only by-design way to obtain new values for the row.